# How to call website with IP address as URL

Tags: html, curl

I want to call my website with IP address.

Something like this `hxxp://255.255.255.1`

Comment: Nice! I want to go swimming today if I can make it and if it stays warm.

Comment: Seriously though, welcome to SO. Your question is much too hazy at the moment to get any useful answers. Please elaborate about your situation, your server setup, how your site is running at the moment, and so on.

Comment: Do you have a public IP? Or is it just your webserver, that needs to be configured correctly?

Answer (score 3):

To access a web site using an IP adress, that web site has to be the default web site for the server.

A web server can host plenty of web sites using the same IP, the server determines which web site will handle the request from the domain name. The server can also have a default web site without a domain name, which handles requests without a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hosted your website on IIS, then right-click on the Default Website directory.
Properties -> Home Directory

Use "Redirection to a url" option. Try that option.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true